# Concatenate rows based on date in teradata

Tags: sql, concatenation, teradata

I have a sample table as below:

```
Date   Type    String  Desired output

01/01   orange  aa      aa
01/10   orange  ab      aa,ab
02/01   orange  bb      aa,ab,bb
02/05   orange  ba      aa,ab,bb,ba
03/15   orange  cc      aa,ab,bb,ba,cc
02/11   apple   aa      aa
```

So now the column 'Date','Type','String' is known, and I would like to return the desired output.The possible way that I can think about now is to use concatenate function and have tried a way like below:

```
select
    t.*,
    row_number()over(partition by Type order by date) as rn,
    lag(string)over(partition by type order by date) as prev_string,
    case when rn = 1 then string when rn = 2 then concat(prev_string, ',', string) end as desired_output
from
    table as t
```

However, by using above code, it can only return if row_number =2. How about try to append next string based on previous output? I'm not sure how to solve this part, and would like to get help with.Also appreciate if you can provide other ideas!

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Only way I  know to do this in teradata is with a recursive CTE.

```
--base data
create volatile table vt_foo 
(dt date,
typ varchar(10),
val varchar(10)
)

on commit preserve rows;

insert into vt_foo values ('2021-01-01','orange','aa');
insert into vt_foo values ('2021-01-10','orange','ab');
insert into vt_foo values ('2021-02-01','orange','bb');
insert into vt_foo values ('2021-02-05','orange','ba');
insert into vt_foo values ('2021-03-15','orange','cc');
insert into vt_foo values ('2021-02-11','apple','aa');

--add row number
create volatile table vt_two as ( select
t.*,
    row_number()over(partition by typ order by dt) as rn
from
    vt_foo as t
) with data
on commit preserve rows;


with  recursive cte (rn , dt ,typ,val, concat_val) as (
select
rn,
dt,
typ,
val,
val as concat_val
from
vt_two
where rn = 1
UNION ALL
select
a.rn,
a.dt,
a.typ,
a.val,
b.concat_val || ',' || a.val
from
vt_two a
inner join cte b
    on a.typ = b.typ
    and a.rn = b.rn + 1
)

select * from cte

order by typ, dt
;
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks! I have a quite similar solution as well, will also post later! Thanks!!